# Calculate night length in r

Tags: r, time, dplyr, lubridate, tibble

An r rookie looking for some help.

I am trying to calculate the night length for a set date in r, but I am having trouble doing so.  To put it in context, survey data is obtained between sunset (-30mins) and sunrise (+30mins) over multiple nights over multiple months. I have been looking at both lubridate and  suncalc packages as possible ways of doing so but cannot get it to work.

The date, data are in the format below:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  site  survey_ID survey_start survey_end
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>        <chr>     
1 LNR   T1        16/05/2019   26/05/2019
2 LNR   T2        16/05/2019   26/05/2019
3 LNR   T3        16/05/2019   19/05/2019
4 LNR   T4        16/05/2019   26/05/2019
5 LNR   T1        06/06/2019   17/06/2019
6 LNR   T2        06/06/2019   17/06/2019
```

The aim will be to create new columns with the number of survey nights between the specified dates, number of minutes from the survey start (30mins before sunset) and end (30mins after sunrise).  This will then be used along side another tibble/data frame that contains data recorded at specific times within these periods.

I have the lat and long for the site as well to get an exact night length so would ideally have code that uses lat and long.

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Welcome to SO @russK. Could you provide us with what you want the resulting data to look like?

Comment: At the moment I am just looking to calculate the number of  minutes for each night surveyed between the survey_start and survey_end. I am based in the north of the UK and season changes in day length can be quite extreme so the night length cannot be assumed.  This would allow me to calculate a total effort (time) for each survey_ID location which I will then use to calculate the number of times the event occurred during the night (per hour/ per night).  I guess that may mean expanding the data to have every night as its own row?

Comment: So for `survey_start` do you want the `sunset_time` or `sunrise_time`? what about for `survey_end`?

Comment: Also how many sites do you have?

Comment: I guess I would need both the sunset_time for survey_start and sunrise_time for survey_end which could then be used to calculate the time between the two.  In this example there is one site with multiple data collection locations (survey_ID).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to calculate the night length based on date, longitude and latitude.

I have implemented the following function from Wikipedia's [Sunrise Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation).

```r
getNightLength <- function(survey_date, latitude, longitude)
{
  survey_date <- strptime(survey_date, "%d/%m/%y")
  time_origin <- strptime("01/01/2000 12:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  n <- as.numeric(difftime(survey_date, time_origin, units = "days"))
  Jstar <- n - longitude / 360
  M <- (357.5291 + 0.98560028 * Jstar) %% 360
  C <- 1.9148 * sin(M * 2*pi/360) + 
       0.0200 * sin(2*M * 2*pi/360) + 
       0.0003 * sin(3*M * 2*pi/360)
  lambda <- (M + C + 180 + 102.9372) %% 360
  Jtransit <- as.double(2451545.000) + 
              as.double(Jstar) + 
              as.double(0.0053 * sin(M * 2*pi/360)) - 
              as.double(0.0069 * sin(lambda * 4*pi/360))
  sindelta <- sin(lambda * 2*pi/360) * sin(23.44 * 2*pi/360)
  delta <- asin(sindelta) * 360/(2*pi)
  cos_omega <- (sin(-0.83 * 2*pi/360) - (sindelta * sin(latitude * 2*pi/360)))/
                (cos(latitude * 2*pi/360) * cos(delta * 2*pi/360))
  omega <- acos(cos_omega) * 360 / (2*pi)
  Jrise <- Jtransit - omega / 360
  Jset <- Jtransit + omega /360
  return((1 - (Jset - Jrise)) * 24)
}
```

Now you can find out the night length like this:

```r
getNightLength("21/05/2019", 55.6, -4.05)
#> [1] 7.427116
```

This tells you how many hours the night was.

Comment: Amazing, thank you.  I am massively impressed. Is it possible to run the getnightLength function to run for a series of dates and then use mutate to merge the dates into a new column in the data? Say, from the date of the first survey (16/05/2019) to the date of the last survey (12/09/2019)?

Comment: @russK Yes, it works on vectors, so you should be able to use it with mutate.

Comment: Okay, thank you.   I will give it a go and see what I can do.